# Saving mp3 through application so that its visible in itunes or music player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mp3, itunes

How can I save a MP3 file that I have just created in the phone memory so that it is discoverable in the music player of the phone and also visible when connected to itunes?
Is it possible to do so? Or does everything will alwaz b stored in the application sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'll be able to just add it to the user's music collection programatically. At the very least, you can save it to the Documents directory which the user has access to from iTunes:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Then you would have to set UIFileSharingEnabled to true in the project's .plist to give the user access to the Documents directory for your app. This setting allows the users to add files to Documents directory as well.

Then they'd have to manually add the files to their collection.

Comment: Thanks A Lot Luke and NSPostWhenIdle. I was unaware of this property called as UIFileSharingEnabled. I hope it solves my issue. I'll do that now.

It also has an alias as "Application supports iTunes file sharing"